# open office formulas grabbing space

Tags: openoffice-writer, frame

On some occasions when an edit is made somewhere in the document that alters the pagination (such as new text that pushes everything down), the formulas will "grab" much, much more space than they need:

[image: a screenshot of the formula that takes up too much space.]

In the above image, there is nothing between the formula and the text. If you put the cursor at the beginning of the text (just before the "w" in "Where") and hit backspace the space will disappear (the text ends up infront of the formula) and upon hitting enter there will be a normal linefeed. This is not much of an issue in and of itself, but it *keeps recurring* unpredictably and messes up the pagination like whack-a-mole.

I am on a macbook pro 10.6.8 with open office 4. The formulas have all the default settings as far as I am aware, including anchoring "as character".